# Read JS object without case sensitivity

Tags: javascript

Lets say we have a Product object with Product.Name, Product.Desc, and Product.Price

but for reasons beyond our control we might recieve a product object with lowercase variables (Product.name, Product.desc, Product.price)

is there a way to interpret variables that are not case sensitive? Or do I have to do some regex `.toLowerCase()` magic?

Thoughts?

Comment: Seems similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915927/how-to-return-a-result-from-json-with-case-insensitive-search-using-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498314/check-for-matching-key-in-object-regardless-of-capitalization

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like Alex Filatov's solution (+1).  Yet, sometimes the name variations are known in advance and/or you may want to accept only certain variations. In this case I've found it easier to do this:

```
 Product.Name = Product.Name || Product.name || default.Name;
```

Just OR the acceptable name variations and optionally add a default value.

Answer (score 2):

You could add some code to correct the object's variable names:

```js
Product.Name = (Product.Name === undefined ? Product.name : Product.Name);
```

However, this would have to be done for every variable in the object.

Answer (score 2):

Compare all the properties of obj with prop.

```
var objSetter = function(prop,val){
  prop = (prop + "").toLowerCase();
  for(var p in obj){
     if(obj.hasOwnProperty(p) && prop == (p+ "").toLowerCase()){
           obj[p] = val;
           break;
      }
   }
}
```